Why do high speed DACS have I/Q
I am working on an application which required D to A conversion of two different high speed signals. The DAC I am using from TI has many functions related to Q/I input signals specifically. I would like to know why many of these high speed DAC have this type of functionality? Also in my application how can I utilize them? Or should I ignore?
The DAC in question is DAC38J82.
My application is a two channel signal generator.

Can you edit the question to include a link to the DAC.

Please list the parts (including data sheet links) that have "this type of functionality". Please also explain what your application is and why you think "this type of functionality" might be useful to you. What do you mean by "how can I utilize them"?

"I/Q" refers to in-phase and quadrature, meaning the \$\sin\$ and \$\cos\$ terms of a real RF signal.  Such functionality is used in SDR (software defined radio) and similar applications.
RF can be direct synthesized from a single-channel DAC, however this is burdensome for very high carrier frequencies; it is more efficient/practical to have a local oscillator (LO) and mix it with baseband DAC output(s) to obtain modulated RF.  This is particularly useful for QAM modulation schemes.
A general-purpose two channel signal generator, with no relationship between channels, would likely not be able to use an I/Q DAC, unless the mixer can be disabled, and both channels provided on output pins.

In addition to the answer, the DAC38J82 datasheet showe there is a mixer_ ena bit in the config2 register which is described as:

When set high, the mixer block is turned on.

I.e. the DAC38J82 does appear to enable the mixer to be disable to allow it to be used to allow use as a signal generator with independent channels.
Also, there are two TI EVMs which have different connections for the DAC output channels:

The DAC3XJ8XEVM User's Guide shows independent transformer coupled outputs SMA outputs for each of the four DAC channels:

The TSW3XJ8XEVM User's Guide shows pairs of DAC channels connected to either:

TRF3705 300MHz to 4GHz Quadrature Modulator
TRF3722 400-MHz to 4.2-GHz Quadrature Modulator with Integrated Wideband PLL/VCO




Where:

The DAC3XJ8XEVM configuration could be an example for the application in the question, which is two channel signal generator.
The TSW3XJ8XEVM configuration is an example for a Direct Digital Synthesis (DDS) Instrument, to synthesise RF.

